# Over (Partition) SQL - No Results

Tags: sql, t-sql, window-functions

I'm trying to use the over (partition) clause to select a a record that selects the record with the max (noteid).

First, when I run this query, I get the expected results which returns two records:

```
select driveid, text, noteid from rpt_notesdetail where driveid='628678'
and Reason in (select codeid from rpt_QuickCodes where DescShort like N'Publicity')
```

And I get 
**DriveID:** 628678, **Text:** All donors will receiv a Free T-shirt, Two Improv tickets and Jersey Mike's Sub Coupon!, **NoteID:** 1410233

**DriveID**: 628678, **Text:** All donors will receive a Free T-shirt, Two Improv tickets and Jersey Mike's Sub Coupon!, **NoteID:** 1410234

But when I try to use the over (partition) SQL:

```
(select text from (select (Text), noteid, max(noteid) over (partition by driveid) as 'max_note'
from rpt_NotesDetail 
where DriveID='628678' 
and createdate = (select max(createdate) from rpt_notesdetail where DriveID='628678') 
and Reason in (select codeid from rpt_QuickCodes where DescShort like N'Publicity')) AS A where A.noteid = A.max_note)
```

Which returns no results.  Any advice on what I am missing here?

Comment: Does your derived table itself return any records (this is the inner query that is in parenthesis and aliased as `a`)?

Comment: Tim, no it does not. I commented out the "createdate = (select max (createdate)" and I am getting results.  So it seems the issue comes from that part of the SQL.

Comment: Is it possible that createdate is null for these records?

Comment: Hey Tim, I don't believe it is possible for this field to be null and I know for this case specifically, they are not null.

Comment: Your max createdate subquery should probably include the Reason that you are using in the derived table, then.

Comment: The last note, the one with `createdate = max(createdate)`, is probably not a publicity, also if `createdate` is a datetime that condition alone will filter out all the rows else then the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing it the hard way. See if you like this way better, and it also allows you to better find the problem. I think it may be because you're not including "and noteid = ..." in your subselect for max(createdate).

```
(select text from 
(
select (Text), noteid, row_number() over (partition by driveid order by noteid desc) as row_num
from rpt_NotesDetail 
where DriveID='628678' 
and createdate = (select max(createdate) from rpt_notesdetail where DriveID='628678') 
and Reason in (select codeid from rpt_QuickCodes where DescShort like N'Publicity')
) AS A 
-- comment out this line to see all rows, possibly showing the data problem
where A.row_num = 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks shriop, unfortunately I'm still not getting results if I leave the "and createdate = (select max (createdate) from rpt_notesdetail" in the code. I'm not entirely sure I need the "and createdate =" in the query at all.

Comment: Hey shriop, you query works as well as long as I nest the Reason query inside the create = (select max(createdate) subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a suggestion from Tim Lehner, I placed the Reason subquery inside the createdate subquery and it works:

```
(select text from (select (Text), noteid, max(noteid) over (partition by driveid) as 'max_note'
from rpt_NotesDetail where DriveID="DriveMaster"."DriveID" and createdate =
(select max(createdate) from rpt_notesdetail where
DriveID="DriveMaster"."DriveID" and Reason in
(select codeid from rpt_QuickCodes where DescShort like N'Publicity'))) AS A
where A.noteid = A.max_note)
```